# EditText with MaxLength fails to stop user input after limit

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard

`EditText` goalName is set with `maxLength` 30 by `InputFilter` (java), `android:maxLength="30"`(xml declaration).

But after 30th letter, letters are not showing in field but clipboard(keyboard suggestion) is showing all letters. And I am showing below how many characters left where its showing 0 characters left after 30th letter.but i have to delete all those extra chars by pressing backspace.when its coming to 30th letter it starts to show 1 char left ...etc..

```
        final InputFilter ip = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30);
        goalName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ip});

        /*To find no of Characters Left for Goal Name*/
        goalName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                noOfChar.setText((30 - s.length()) + "  characters left");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Why are you using `addTextChangedListener` for counter. Instead of this you can use `TextInputLayout` which is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you move in new design of android without taking load of edittext.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="30"
            app:counterTextAppearance="@style/TextLimitStyle">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
              android:id="@+id/etMessage"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="top"
              android:hint="Say something..."
              android:maxLength="30" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(s.length() > 30) s = s.subSequence(0,30);
            goalName.requestFocus(30);
            noOfChar.setText((30 - s.length()) + "  characters left");

        }
```

Just test because maybe it should finish in 29 not 30, I'm not sure about this part

And try to remove the filter:

```
//final InputFilter ip = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(30);
//goalName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ip});
```

let just the Xml declaration:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:maxLength="30"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Comment: Its not working. I'm facing this issue only for Text(String) not for Numbers.like 1122.. only 30 characters allowing and when i press once backspace it start removing from 30th position. If i'm adding at last strings then strings start appending ,,like i have to remove all extra typed letters.

Comment: You tried my suggestion? because there is no point about numbers in my answer. Could you please edit you question with picture and the debug of the code so I can understand better the behaviour of the String? Because this works on my code.

Comment: I tried yours. Scenario 1: edittext="12122....." (length =30) its working fine. Scenario 2: edittext="1233.....aaa" it shows only 30 characters but i typed 35 chars and i have to press backspace 5 times to come exact 30th letter(cursor)

Comment: Sorry @RagavendraM I cannot understand what you mean with you example/scenario to help you more.

Comment: @RagavendraM can you debug so we can the the values for the String S? because is showing only 30, but maybe there is more. If is not that we can maybe work with focus. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I checked in stock android OS its working fine. But in oppo ColorOS keyboard having suggestions(30+letters). I tried with nosuggestions declration in xml but its still persists.

Answer (score 0):

When I used `android:maxLength` with `android:inputType="textMultiline"` I ran into the same issue where my EditText wasn't respecting the character limit. I found that using an [`InputFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter)/[`LengthFilter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.LengthFilter) helped make this work.

Example usage in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val MAX_CHARS_LENGTH: Int = ...
val myEditText: EditText = ...
myEditText.filters = arrayOf(LengthFilter(MAX_CHARS_LENGTH))
```

For the character count display, I'd recommend overriding `afterTextChanged` instead of `onTextChanged`

Answer (score -1):

```
android:maxLength="30"
```

Put this in your EditText in the layout file

Like this

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_textbox_new_background"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="5"
        android:maxLength="500"
        android:padding="10dip" />
```